# internal server 500 webmethod C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Estoy programando en asp.net

y estoy enviando datos por medio de un ajax a un webmethod, pero al momento de realizarlo me marca el error 500 internal server error

```
function setPropceso(infoPagos, conk, i) {
        //alert("finalizo");
        var stringData = JSON.stringify(infoPagos);
        var stringConekta = JSON.stringify(conk);
        var data = JSON.stringify({ 'reserva': stringData, 'coneckta': stringConekta });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/remate-de-viajes/Default.aspx/pago",
            data: data,
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = data.d;
            }
        });
}
```

Asi está mi webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
    public static Confirmacion pago(infoReserva reserva , infoConekta coneckta)
    {
        Confirmacion c = new Confirmacion();


        return c;
    }
```

Por mas que he cambiado, el nombre del webmethod, también he probado enviando otros tipos de info, me sigue dando error, he intentado enviar la data sin convertirla a JSON pero también me marca error.

Comment: Ya intentas verificar los routes (Nombres de los servicio?)

Comment: nombres de los servicios?? que son esos?

Comment: Creo saber en que estas fallando , realiza esta prueba , cambia esto `JSON.stringify({ 'reserva': stringData, 'coneckta': stringConekta });` por esto : `"{ reserva:"' + stringData +'", coneckta:"'+ stringConekta + '"  }";` me avisas si funciona para agregar la respuesta.

Comment: Ok lo intento ;)

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez Funciono ? como lo solucionaste?

Comment: no no funcionó, sigo con el mismo problema

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez pero ps ovio agregaste el JSON.stringify( verdad? Mejor dicho agrega esto `JSON.stringify( "{ reserva:"' + stringData +'", coneckta:"'+ stringConekta + '" }")`

Comment: Una cosa que me da a mí que pueda ser la causa: los parámetros del método en servidor, son de tipo infoReserva e infoConekta. ¿has probado a cambiarlos ambos por los tipos string, y ya dentro del método, una vez que has comunicado, parsearlos a los tipos de objetos que necesitas?

Comment: @sgrojillo Gracias por tu respuesta, sin duda ese fue el problema

Comment: Me alegro haber sido de ayuda :)

Comment: @sgrojillo publica tu respuesta para que sea aceptada y asi sea de ayuda para otros usuarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de ver que mi comentario ha ayudado a aclarar la duda, y por aportar una solución a aquellas personas con un mismo problema, os planteo la solución un poco más desarrollada.

El error de este problema eran los **parámetros del WebMethod en servidor**:

```
public static Confirmacion pago(infoReserva reserva , infoConekta coneckta)
```

Tanto **reserva** como **coneckta** eran parámetros de entrada que chocaban con los parámetros de envío desde JSON en la parte de cliente, declarados como tipo **string**. Al intentar conectar con el método web, no era capaz el servidor de resolver los parámetros enviados por cliente.

La solución sería definir el webmethod con los parámetros de tipo string, y si fuera necesario convertirlos a los objetos de tipo **infoReserva** y **infoConekta**, hacerlo dentro del código. En el ejemplo facilitado del error no viene ningún manejo de los parámetros del WebMethod, así que con ánimo de aclarar mi explicación, permitidme la pequeña licencia de diseñar dos clases y mostrar cómo parsear el valor de los parámetros string en dichos objetos:

**Definición de clases infoReserva y infoConekta:**

```
public class infoReserva
{
    public string codigoReserva {get; set; }
}

public class infoConekta
{
    public string codigoConekta {get; set; }
}
```

**WebMethod con su contenido actualizado:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static Confirmacion pago(string reserva , string coneckta)
{
    infoReserva eReserva = new infoReserva() { codigoReserva = reserva };
    infoConekta eConeckta = new infoConekta() { codigoConekta = coneckta };

    Confirmacion c = new Confirmacion();
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Adicional a eso, aprendí que hay que hacer coincidir los tipos de datos que se están enviando en el objeto de JS para que coincida con el objeto que recibe el webmethod. 

Pero para ser más fácil, pueden enviarlo todo como string y después parsearlo de lado servidor